# ng-repeat fail with $ symbol

Tags: html, angularjs

When a try to ng-repeat an object by its props/values it fail when the prop name is "$"

```
let values = {
  "$": "110",
  "BTC": "0.2"
}

<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in values">{[{k}]} {[{v}]}</div>
```

The plunkr below show the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SiNayH0nRXXmlWBDVCOr?p=preview

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Because ngRepeat skips props that starts with `$` sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ngRepeat docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> ngRepeat will silently ignore object keys starting with $, because it's a prefix used by Angular for public ($) and private ($$) properties.

Answer (score 1):

Object keys that begins with **`dollar($) sign`** will not be recognized by an ng-repeat as `$` is a reserved character in angular.

Angular used `dollar($)` sign for certain components, e.g. `$resource` or `$http` ..

Here, this is still an open [**issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6266).